# how do I use a hyphen when defining an acronym in the middle of the term?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

Example:

"Metropolitan Statistical Area (MSA) level unemployment"

I need a hyphen between "Area" and "level".  Later in the document the term appears as "MSA-level".

Should it be:

"Metropolitan Statistical Area- (MSA) level unemployment"  [note the spaces/lack thereof]

or

"Metropolitan Statistical Area (MSA) -level unemployment"  [note the spaces/lack thereof]

or

"Metropolitan Statistical Area-(MSA) level unemployment"  [note the spaces/lack thereof]

or

"Metropolitan Statistical Area (MSA)-level unemployment"  [note the spaces/lack thereof]

or

"Metropolitan Statistical Area-level (MSA) unemployment"

or

"Metropolitan Statistical Area level (MSA) unemployment"  [no hyphen at all]

or

???

Note: this is the first instance of the term/acronym being introduced within the document, so definition here is necessary.  (Or is it?)

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing my answer purely on what looks correct to me, based on my knowledge and experience.  It may be that some manual will have what will be considered the correct answer.

This one gets my vote:

Metropolitan Statistical Area (MSA)-level unemployment

You've put the acronym directly after the term and added the hyphen directly on to the acronym.  As a reader of this, I would assume that the term **MSA-level** is meant.