# How can I introduce an acronym parenthetically in a hyphenated compound?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms, parentheses

How do I introduce the acronym for "deep learning" in the following case:
"Deep learning-based"

Example:

> Deep learning (DL)-based

or

> Deep learning-based (DL-based)

Comment: I guess it's followed by something like *experience:* "Deep learning-based experience" there is a potential problem there as it **could** say that the experience is deep, not the learning.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Yes, it is.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148705/how-do-i-use-a-hyphen-when-defining-an-acronym-in-the-middle-of-the-term) but I'm not sure about the only answer, which isn't referenced and I'm not sure I like. Rewriting is the obvious solution.

Comment: Please note that the default definition for 'acronym' nowadays (check in dictionaries) includes the condition that the abbreviation be pronounced as a word. So NASA: acronym but BBC: **initialism**.

Comment: If Deep learning deserves an abbreviation, it deserves to show us how we got there: Deep Learning (DL). Then it's DL-based.

Comment: Hopefully the question I found has a good enough answer. It at least has references to examples in the wild of how this type of thing is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Rework and add a preposition to add the acronym for Deep Learning:

> Based on Deep Learning (DL)

Reads better as well. If you must, you can subsequently used DL-based.